# Finding the length of a spiral

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

I need to find the length of a spiral. The spiral start at a certain radius $R_1$ and ends at a smaller radius $R_2$. As the spiral spins inwards, the distance between each arm of the spiral decreases but not by a constant amount (as the radius decreases, the decrease in radius is smaller and smaller).

I tried using the archemedian spiral equation ($r = a + b\theta$) and making $b$ and $a$ function of $r$ (where $a$ is start radius and $2\pi b$ is the decrease in radius per revolution),and then using a standard spiral length integral formula but this seems to give the wrong answer. I think that the formula above doesn't apply to my situation, would anyone know a better way to model it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula $\int ds$

Where $ds = \sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}$

We can write $$x = r\cos\theta = (a+b\theta)\cos\theta \Rightarrow dx = b\cos\theta -(a+b\theta)\sin\theta\hspace{1mm}d\theta$$

And  $$y = r\sin\theta = (a+b\theta)\sin\theta  \Rightarrow dx = b\sin\theta +(a+b\theta)\cos\theta\hspace{1mm}d\theta$$

$ $

$ $

You will have $$ds = \sqrt{b^2+(a+b\theta)^2}\hspace{1mm} d\theta$$

$ $

Integrate $$\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} \sqrt{b^2+(a+b\theta)^2}\hspace{1mm} d\theta$$

$ $

You need to find $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ as needed

Comment: Thanks, but when I solve that equation I get a wrong answer. In my case b is a variable which depends on r but I think that's not the equation I should be using. Is there another equation for a spiral?

Comment: You need to tell the complete question, i don't get u

Comment: It's an experiment I'm doing. Basically a pin is sitting on a disk which is spinning. The pin moves along the radius of the spinning disk at a constant speed and is prevented from flying off the disk. To maintain a constant tangential velocity of the pin (the one caused by the spinning of the disk), the speed of the spinning disk is increased as the pin approaches the centre. This track which the pin follows is a spiral where the distance between each arm decreases as the spin moves towards the centre and I need to find the length of the spiral

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thought: since your spiral has spacings between arms that are decreasing by less and less as the object spirals inwards, we can start your spiral with a formula that makes the spacings increase as a function of theta, like this: 
r = a +b*theta^1.1   or
r = a + b*theta^1.2 
Now this or some other ever-increasing formula should model the behavior just right, it won't solve nearlty as easily as the Archimedean spiral equation, given that b^2 will become something with theta. The reason the other method didn't work is that the archimedean spiral equation describes spirals with a constant spacing between spiral arms, and your spiral doesn't share this behavior.